# Satellizer installation error in windows

Tags: node.js, installation, npm, satellizer

I am trying to install Satellizer.

But getting error.

Can you guide me to understand whats this error is, and how can I fix this.

[image]

I have node version v5.1.0 and npm version 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the `Satellizer` as a decency inside your `package.json`

Or
 That the project name is the same of one your depended package(s)

---

If it not a depended package, there used to be some error with `npm v3.5.X` so try to update your npm version and then re-install it.

I would also recommend to test it with node v4.X since v5 might contain those kind of bugs